# Why am I getting a Sorry you are not allowed to upload this file type with m4a files?

Tags: mime-types

“GMT20200617-005050_123.m4a” has failed to upload.
Sorry, you are not allowed to upload this file type.

The files are valid and the other items I've add to this array work properly.

Here is my code in functions.php

```
function my_custom_upload_mimes($mimes = array()) {
  // Add a key and value for the CSV file type
  $mimes['csv']  = "text/csv";
  $mimes['svg']  = "image/svg"; 
  $mimes['jfif'] = "image/jfif";    
  $mimes['m4a']  = "audio/m4a"; 
return $mimes;
}
add_action('upload_mimes', 'my_custom_upload_mimes');
```

They do upload properly if I add the ALLOW_UNFILTERED... #define to wp-config.php